# Переход на сайт при нажатии кнопки в Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Как с помощью нажатия на кнопку перейти на сайт? Разрабатываю мобильное приложение в Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта.

Можно [вот так](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?tabs=android).

```
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("https://ru.stackoverflow.com"));
}
```

Либо можно [так](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=android).

```cs
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await Browser.OpenAsync(new Uri("https://ru.stackoverflow.com"));
}
```

Comment: В этих 2 вариантах вообще нет разницы?